# MySQL where and/or not returning correct records

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with the following query returning the incorrect records that contain displ = 1.

I end up getting the correct selection for `discipline = 6 or 7 (or others specified)` but it returns only records containing `displ = 0`  when in fact I need `displ = 1`.

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT schedule.id, schedule.entryid, schedule.venue, schedule.venuedate, 
schedule.venuetime, schedule.schednote, schedule.classnbr,
schedule.classname, schedule.grade, schedule.discipline, schedule.displ, 
schedule.hidename, schedule.lastn,schedule.firstn,schedule.duetfirst,schedule.duetlast,
schedule.triofirst,schedule.triolast,schedule.titleselection1,schedule.composer1,
schedule.titleselection2, schedule.composer2, schedule.titleselection3, schedule.composer3, 
schedule.groupname, venue.venue, venue.venuelocation 
FROM schedule
INNER JOIN venue ON schedule.venue = venue.venue 
WHERE schedule.displ = 1 
AND schedule.discipline = 3 or schedule.discipline = 4 or schedule.discipline = 5 or schedule.discipline = 6 or schedule.discipline = 7
```

Comment: I returns records that contain the correct discipline but it only gives me records where displ = 0 and it should give displ = 1

Comment: eg:  simplified data for illustration
   
id   |   venue  |  discipline  |  displ
1    |   vn1      |  2               |  1
2    |  vn8       |  6               |  0
3    |  vn8       |  6               |  1
4    |  vn3       |  5               |  1
5    |  vn8       |  7               |  0
6    |  vn4       |  1               |  1

expected result display ids 3 and 4
first result ids 2 and 5 which is wrong as displ = 0 on those.
after using example: where schedule.displ = 1 and schedule.discipline in (3,4,5,6,7) now no records at all.  tried on mysql workbench and phpmysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...or better yet, use `IN`

```
where schedule.displ = 1 and schedule.discipline in (3,4,5,6,7)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9650f/1)

Comment: now it returns 0 records.  I just replaced the where line above.  idea?

Comment: eg:  simplified data for illustration
   
id   |   venue  |  discipline  |  displ
1    |   vn1      |  2               |  1
2    |  vn8       |  6               |  0
3    |  vn8       |  6               |  1
4    |  vn3       |  5               |  1
5    |  vn8       |  7               |  0
6    |  vn4       |  1               |  1


expected result display ids 3 and 4

originally I was getting ids 2 and 5 which is incorrect because displ = 0 on those.

now I am getting no records at all.  I tried this on mysql workbench as well as on phpmysql.

Comment: Please edit your question to add example data and expected output.

Comment: Thank you, this does work as I had fixed a syntax error!

Answer (score 1):

You should uses parenthesis like that :

```
Where schedule.displ = 1 and 
(
    schedule.discipline = 3 or 
    schedule.discipline = 4 or 
    schedule.discipline = 5 or 
    schedule.discipline = 6 or 
    schedule.discipline = 7
)
```

;)

Explication :

When you dont help mysql to know priority, he reads from left to right :

```
( (schedule.displ = 1 and schedule.discipline = 3 ) or schedule.discipline = 4 ) or schedule.discipline = 5 ...
```

So, he returns every lines where discipline = 4, 5, 6, 7 and lines with discipline = 3 and displ = 1